# How to find North and South in the Nether

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have been trying for days to find a Nether Fortress. I've looked up different ways on how to find one and I happened to stumble upon an answer that might help me.
[The question he asked](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/75073/any-useful-strategies-for-finding-a-nether-fortress)
was just what I was looking for. Someone answered him and said, "There are infinite nether fortresses in the nether. They spawn in rows every 200-400 blocks along the world's North/South axis."
I don't even know how to find the North/South axis. I'm on bedrock edition and all I can see are coordinates. And, I'm pretty sure you can't use a compass in the Nether, so what do I do? And how do I find the North/South cords?

Comment: A compass wouldn't help in the Overworld anyway, they point towards the world spawn point, not North :)

Comment: @AJPerez oh yeah. Ur right, haha.

Comment: Sorry to drop in, but I feel I should mention Nether Fortress generation has changed since that Q&A was written. If yo uare playing post-1.16 Nether Fortress spawn is different now, and every direction is as good an any other to search: https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Nether_Fortress I too spent six-ish hours before finding my first Nether Fortress after the update so you are not alone in this

Comment: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8693/how-can-i-determine-which-direction-im-facing

Comment: (The question linked by qwr is the same thing but in Java Edition, so not a duplicate)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Turn "show coordinates" on. Then just move around. The negative Z direction is North and the positive Z south.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 I was watching the sun and moon, and it appears your right. I'm pretty sure north is positive Z then right?

Comment: https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Coordinates yes, negative Z = north

Comment: dishonoroubales

Comment: @DeepDeadpool ?

Comment: @user253751 but negative Z is north

Comment: @Penguin Well, it's computer co-ordinates. Top-left is (0, 0), down the screen is positive y… erm, z.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 lmao but u literally said from math class (or that guy did)

Answer (score 44):

You can use the [south-east rule](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/55505/219480), which works in all dimensions. Place 4 pieces of minecart track in a T shape, with the intersection piece last, and it will favor south or east. Do this twice, with the second T rotated 90 degrees from the first one, and you'll be able to uniquely identify which way is which.

Comment: This is the best "in universe" method since it doesn't rely on debug/coordinate info, but it's also kind of funny because it's like a paranormal behavior that is well documented in universe.

Comment: Also doesn't rely on textures, used to use cobble to tell which direction things were, since it had a very pronounced L shape before the texture updates